# Cloudwatch dashboard のデータを cli から取得したい

Tags: aws, aws-cloudwatch

今、 Cloudwatch 上のダッシュボードを、 aws のコンソール上で設定しました。

コンソールでログインすれば、もちろん、このデータは確認できるのですが、複数のアカウントをまたがって作業したり、セキュリティ(２段階認証)などを付与していくと、いちいちコンソールにログインしなければ確認できないのは、不便に感じました。

### 質問

- aws cloudwatch 上で定義したダッシュボードのデータを、 cli から取得することはできますか？

  - 例えば、期間を指定すれば、そのダッシュボードのデータが json などで返ってきたらよいな、と思いながら質問しています。

Answer (score 0):

「aws cloudwatch cli」でgoogle検索するとドキュメントがヒットしました。

[get-dashboard — AWS CLI 1.16.230 Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/get-dashboard.html)

> ```
> get-dashboard
>   --dashboard-name <value>
>  [--cli-input-json <value>]
>  [--generate-cli-skeleton <value>]
> ```

出力として`DashboardBody -> (string)`などが返されるようです。
JSON形式のようですが、フォーマットの詳細は以下を参照とのこと。

[Dashboard Body Structure and Syntax - Amazon CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/CloudWatch-Dashboard-Body-Structure.html)